# Postgres: searching json array for int field value

Tags: postgresql

Following this documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html I came across this syntax for searching a json array for a constant value using single quotes.

I'd like to do the same but search for the value of a field in a table I'm joining to.  I've tried a number of variations of this:

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableB.json_array FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON (tableB.json_array)::jsonb @> tableA.id;
```

But am always running into type-related issues.  Does the `@>` operator only work with constants?  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What data type is the column `json_array`? If it indeed contains a JSON array, then it does not contain "values using single quotes". And which Postgres version are you using? 9.5 is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in `JSON ARRAY` format then you can use Postgres `jsonb_array_elements_text` function which is extracting values of array elements. After doing this you can easily use key values in a query or on where conditions.

Sample query for you:

```
-- sample format for json_array field:  [{"id": 110}, {"id": 115}, {"id": 130}, {"id": 145}, {"id": 152}, {"id": 165}]  
select b.* from tableB b
cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(b.json_array) b2(pvalue) 
where 
    (b2.pvalue::jsonb->'id')::int4 > 100 
    -- (b2.pvalue::jsonb->'id')::int4 = 102
    -- (b2.pvalue::jsonb->'id')::int4 in (50, 51, 55)
```